# Transferring Data Between Sheets (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to do a complicated data transfer between one "master" sheet and multiple "sub" sheets. Today is my first day with Excel VBA so I'm pretty lost haha. I decided to start small and transfer data from one cell of one sheet to the other sheet but I keep on getting this error of "Cannot jump to 'Sheets' because it is hidden". Can anyone please lend me a hand? Thanks in advance.

Shi

```
Sub transfer()
Dim strSourceSheet As String, strDestinationSheet As String, sourceData As String
strSourceSheet = "profile list"
Sheets(strSourceSheet).Activate
sourceData = Sheets(strSourceSheet).Cells(30, 37).Value
strDestinationSheet = "RADIANT OPTO-ELECTRONICS CORP."
Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Activate
Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Cells(C, 11) = sourceData
End Sub
```

Comment: Issue has been resolved!

Comment: post your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll rarely need to activate a sheet or range.  You should a videos [Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=5) and [Worksheets, Charts and Sheets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3OE7Z62oGM&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5&index=6)

```
Sub transfer()
    Const strDestinationSheet As String = "RADIANT OPTO-ELECTRONICS CORP."
    Const strSourceSheet As String = "profile list"

    Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Cells(C, 11) = Sheets(strSourceSheet).Cells(30, 37).Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Sheet(strSourceSheet)` is hidden, you can't activate it, you need to unhide it first.

Use the following if to unhide a sheet if it is hidden:

```
' The sheet is hidden then unhide it
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSourceSheet).Visible = False Then ' Check if one is visable.
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(strSourceSheet).Visible = True
End If
```

The same goes for your second sheet `Sheets(strDestinationSheet)`

However, having said that, if all you want is to copy cells between sheets, it's better to avoid **Select** and **Activate**, all you have to do is :

```
'However, having said that, if all you want is to copy cells betwwen sheets all you have to do is :

Sub transfer()

Dim strSourceSheet As String, strDestinationSheet As String, sourceData As String

strSourceSheet = "profile list"
strDestinationSheet = "RADIANT OPTO-ELECTRONICS CORP."

' this is how you referrence Cell(C11), if that's what you meant
Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Cells(11, "C") = Sheets(strSourceSheet).Cells(30, 37).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That is helpful.